# Bundler is being blocked by Rubygems website using RVM with Ruby 2.3.0

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I am using Jenkins to automate a build process. I am pulling code from git, then running a bundle install to load the correct gems. However when I do so, I am getting an error message (see below) indicating that the connection is being blocked. I get the same error running a bundle install as the jenkins user on the command line. However, I can do a wget on the command line and retrieve the file. I can also use a bundle install using jruby with jenkins, and I do not get the error.

My network administrators insist it isn't them. I am running through a proxy, but that does not seem to be the issue as it works in the other cases. I am running from a command line. There are no viruses from browsers as I don't have any browsers installed on the machine, despite what the error message indicates.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this response? Failing that, does anyone have any ideas on a workaround?

**I am running:**
centos/6.6
rvm/1.26.11
bundler/1.11.2
rubygems/2.5.1
ruby/2.3.0

```
>bundle install  
Fetching source index from http://rubygems.org/  
Net::HTTPForbidden: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01  
Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Notification: Security: Browser</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 0px;
  color: #2970A6;
}
a:link {
    color: #2970A6;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #2970A6;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
p.buttonlink {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.copyright {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666666;
  margin: 5px 5px 0px 30px;

}
.details {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #969696;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 35px;
}

.shadow {
  border: 3px solid #9f9f9f;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  margin: 10px 35px 0px 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 600px;

  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cccccc;
  /* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5,
Direction=135, Color='cccccc')";
  /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135,
Color='cccccc');
}
.logo {
  border: none;
  margin: 5px 5px 0px 30px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="logo"></div><p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="shadow">
<h1>This Page Cannot Be Displayed</h1>

<p>
Based on your organization's access policies, requests from your
computer have been blocked because it has been determined to be a security
threat to the organization's network. Your browser may have been compromised
by a malware/spyware agent identified as &quot;bundler/1.11.2 rubygems/2.5.1
ruby/2.3.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) command/install
options/path,disable_shared_gems ci/jenkins c519813b2ff2a1bc&quot;.
</p>




<p>
If you have questions, please contact
your organization's network administrator 
</p>

<p>

</p>




</div>

<div class="details"><p>
Date: Tue, 15 Mar 2016 19:18:13 GMT<br />
Username: <br />
Source IP: 172.18.77.77<br />
URL: GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rake-0.4.8.gemspec.rz<br />
Category: <br />
Reason: BLOCK-BROWSER<br />
Notification: BROWSER
</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That totally looks like a proxy blocking access. You might try changing the source to https (which you should do anyway)

Comment: @FrederickCheung That's good information, thank you. I don't know how to get bundler to use https. I'll see if there's a flag.

Comment: Just change the source in the Gemfile

Comment: @FrederickCheung Ok, thanks. I found instructions here under the headings "Custom git sources" and "security": http://bundler.io/git.html

Comment: You just need to change the `source "http://rubygems.org"` line

Comment: @FrederickCheung Yep, that did it. If you want to add that as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to edit the Gemfile file and change:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
```

to:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
```